# Setting Successive LocalNotification in android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to set alarm to be raised at specified time for a phonegap project in android. I have used `LocalNotification` to do the same, and it works good and the alarm is raised for the first time.

When I receive of the alarm I need to add another notification so that this occurs in chain.

I tried calling `loadUrl()` to invoke the script method to add another notification. But the method is not trigerring.
Also tried calling the execute method of `LocalNotification` inside `AlarmReceiver`, but at this stage the context become null 
and therefore results in NullPointer exception.

Do help me on this.